# Bootstrap stacked dropdown menu not dropping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

So my site (jakepotterryan.com) has a vertical nav menu floating to the left. I recently tried creating a dropdown menu containing my projects. I decided to go with Bootstrap stacked nav but I can't seem to get the menu to actually *do* anything.

maybe it has to do with space constraints within my container that maybe won't allow the menu to expand?

```
         <ul class="nav navbar-stacked">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.php">About Me</a>
                </li>

                <!--dropdown-->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Projects<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog/blog.php">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blink/blink.php" target="_blank">Blink Securities</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="HeadTunes/index.php" target="_blank">Head Tunes LLC.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://chubfeed.wordpress.com/" target="_blank">Chub_feed</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>  
            <li>
                    <a href="Real_Resumenorefs.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Seems fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/EDHU6 Boostrap loaded? Any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

You need to load jQuery *before* Bootstrap (and any other library, plugin or function that uses it).

Comment: How do I do that? You mean in the heading?